# Creating a UAC like environment

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, winapi

I want to create an environment like UAC. i.e. my dialog should appear to the user and unless he responds to it, i want to disable the background. User should not be able to carry out any activity.

For this purpose I created a new desktop and display my dialog on the new desktop. But i want something like UAC where the background seems disabled (or transparent??).

Does anyone know how to go about it?

Thanks
Rohit

Comment: I would be *so* pissed if random applications started doing this. Please reconsider.

Comment: Least you can do when you are told to do something.

Comment: I found what i wanted.
http://www.ureader.com/msg/14721854.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"User should not be able to carry out any activity".

Does this include locking the desktop, logging off, shutting down, rebooting, etc. Does it include preventing another user from trying to log in?

This sort of behaviour generally requires altering the session management for windows - it's the same sort of behaviour that dongle/token based systems use.

This MSDN Article might be worth a read to see if it's more along the lines of what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx

Comment: I want to mimic the secure desktop mode of UAC. The user can cancel the dialog on the new desktop and carry on with his work. But if the user wants to proceed using my application he will have to Select Continue or something. 

I have managed to get it work by taking screenshot of current desktop and displaying it on the new desktop thus giving the illusion of the original desktop in background. Only problem now is darkening the screenshot so that it appears disabled.

Just wanted to know if there is an easy rather than doing the way i am doing now?